# JavaScript: store function in an object, but execute it in local context

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

I have an object like this:

```
objectx = {
    1: {
        name: "first",
        loadFunction: function() { 
            $(target).load("http://stackoverflow.com #question", function() {
                // do something else
            });
        }
    },
    2: {
        name: "second",
        loadFunction: function() { 
            $(target).load("http://stackoverflow.com #answer", function() {
                // do something else
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the functions with objectx[1].loadFunction(), they don't have the local context, so I would have to pass everything as argument or make my variables global. For example:

```
function doSomething() {
    var target; // this variable holds a reference to a DOM object

    objectx[1].loadFunction()
}
```

> target is not defined

How do I execute the functions so that they are aware of the context they are called from?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible (the way you do it), due to how lexical scope works in JavaScript.

You want a function argument, plain and simple. Writing functions that depend on global state is bad style anyway.

```
var objectx = {
    1: {
        name: "first",
        loadFunction: function(target) { 
            $(target).load("http://stackoverflow.com #question", function() {
                // do something else
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
function doSomething() {
    var target; // this variable holds a reference to a DOM object

    objectx[1].loadFunction(target);
}
```

Done.

Comment: That's how I do it now, but it requires too many arguments and makes future changes to the program difficult.

Comment: Then you have poor program structure and need to improve that. Functions with many arguments are bad style as well. Externalizing those arguments into some sort of global state is not a solution to that problem. If you explain what you're *actually* trying to do, I might be able to suggest an improvement.

Comment: I have several elements on my site. The program randomly selects one, looks for a suitable replacement and changes the content according to information stored in the object. Background(-color), text etc. It then fetches external content through a proxy, formats it and places it in a div inside the element. For the fetching and formatting I'm using these functions, because they need to be different for every object and it made sense to me to store them alogg with the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible in JavaScript. JS uses lexical [scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). What you seem to be looking for is dynamic scope.

The best you can do is either pass arguments, define it in scope, or use a global variable (less than recommended).